# Query with join doesn't work

Tags: database

I have custom tables and want to execute this query.

```
select displayname from foolzz_users_profile
join foolzz_user_has_user on (fk_user1=1 or fk_user2=1)
where fk_users_uid != 1;
```

The "1" numbers will be replaced with the users uid.
This is my query in the module.

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$uid = $user->get('uid')->value;

$query = \Drupal::database()->select('foolzz_users_profile', 'e');
$query->fields('e', array('fk_users_uid,displayname'));
$query->join('foolzz_user_has_user','d','d.fk_user1=:uid OR d.fk_user2=:uid',array(':uid' => $uid));
$query->condition('e.fk_users_uid', $uid, '<>');

$friendlist = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

I'm searching for hours and still couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things...firstly

```
$query->condition('data.fk_users_uid', !$uid);
```

`!$uid` returns `false` when used on a positive non-zero integer in PHP (and `true` for zero, the anonymous user).

You probably meant:

```
$query->condition('data.fk_users_uid', $uid, '<>');
```

Secondly, you're using the same alias for both tables. That'll never work. Change the one in the join to `data2` or something:

```
$query->join('foolzz_user_has_user', 'data2', 'data2.fk_user1=:uid OR data2.fk_user2=:uid', array(':uid' => $uid));
```

Comment: I think this ís not the only mistake I made. So i changed that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah there was one more, edited the answer

Comment: After your last suggestion i noticed I had a small typo in my own code but not here in this question. Thank you for your answer. The problem is solved :)

Comment: [Statement::fetchAllAssoc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Statement.php/function/Statement%3A%3AfetchAllAssoc/8.3.x), so you should be able to do `$friendlist = $result->fetchAllAssoc('some_column');`